# Задать значение переменной через аргумент функции

Tags: c++, функции

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
void setNumber(string array[3], int t)
{
    array[0] = "255";
    t = 255;
}
int main()
{
    int t = 1;
    string array[3] = { "1","2","3" };
    setNumber(array, t);
    cout << array[0] << endl;        //обратить внимание на эти строчки кода
    cout << t;                       //
}
//консоль array[0] = 255 
//t = 1  <- ???
```

Почему в данном коде элемент массива сохраняет значение через функцию `setNumber` а переменная `t` типа `int` нет?

Comment: Чтобы избежать подобных неприятностей определяйте параметры константными, например; `void setNumber(const string array[3], int t)`

Answer (score 0):

Потому что сигнатура функции на самом деле `setNumber(string * array, int t)`. C-style массивы в C/C++ нельзя передать в функцию по значению, а тип такого аргумента всегда будет указателем. Передавайте все по ссылке, тогда изменения будет видны в `main`

```
void setNumber(string (& array)[3], int & t)
```